# How do I write xPath for the XML file

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, automation

How do I write a xPath for below XML to fetch the data from field "fname"
-- where field 'Department' contains data "IT"
-- and ID and ImgID are same.

-- Below is sample XML ----

[Sample XML][1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dbdump>
<database name="testDatabase" schemaVer="1.0.0">
    <table name="testTable">
        <row>
            <field name="ID">1</field>
            <field name="lname">Smith</field>
            <field name="fname">Tom</field>
            <field name="department">HR</field>
            <field name="ImgID">0</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="ID">2</field>
            <field name="lname">K</field>
            <field name="fname">John</field>
            <field name="department">IT</field>
            <field name="ImgID">2</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="ID">3</field>
            <field name="lname">D</field>
            <field name="fname">Sam</field>
            <field name="department">IT</field>
            <field name="ImgID">3</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="ID">4</field>
            <field name="lname">J</field>
            <field name="fname">Tina</field>
            <field name="department">IT</field>
            <field name="ImgID">0</field>
        </row>
    </table>
</database>
</dbdump>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add your XML as a text. Images are not helpful.

Comment: Added sample XML as a Text

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: I was just able to fetch all data from field "fname" using below xPath but i need help to add additional conditions and see if i can filter and get only those data mentioned in my question (get "fname" value when 'department'=HR and both ID and imgID values are same) 

xpathExpression = "//database[@name='testDatabase']/table[@name='testTable']/row/field[@name='fname']/text()";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly more precise and efficient XPath:

```
/dbdump/database/table/row[field[@name="department"] = "IT"][field[@name="ID"] = field[@name="ImgID"]]/field[@name="fname"]/text()
```